# how to add spinner in react native?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

am stuck with a problem , I want to add spinner before loading my Welcome page , please tell me how to do? I have install react native lottie package for spinner. if you have any query please free feel to ask.

> welcome.js

This is the welcome .js file where i want to add loader before loading my welcome page.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";

export const Welcome = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View>
      {loading ? (
        <LottieView source={require("../assets/loader.json")} autoPlay loop />
      ) : null}
      <Image
        style={{
          height: 300,
          width: 250,
          alignItems: "center",
          marginLeft: 50,
          marginTop: 100,
        }}
        source={require("../images/Welcome.png")}
      />
      <Text style={styles.logintext}>
        Log In with your Data that you entered during your Registration.
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.btn1} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("signup")}>
          Sign Up
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.btn2} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("signin")}>
          Sign In
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logintext: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginHorizontal: 35,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  btn1: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFA500",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#fff",
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 70,
    marginHorizontal: 60,
    borderRadius: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  btn2: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#000000",
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 40,
    marginHorizontal: 60,
    borderRadius: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 18,
    borderColor: "#FFA500",
    borderWidth: 3,
  },
});

// export default Welcome;
```

Comment: Your code and question is not clear, is this your welcome page and do you want to display a loader before you load the login/signup?

Comment: i want to display loader before load welcome page

Comment: But, is this the welcome page as well ?

Comment: @AppyMango welcome page is my starting page , so I at the beginning before load my welcome page show loader and after show welcome page some bit seconds, i hope you will clear what i want

Comment: @TusharBhakare your 'loading' state does not update anywhere within the code. Hence it never sets to 'true'

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the spinner only if the loading is true, but you are also rendering other components without waiting for the loader to be false.

Try the below example:

```
{!loading && (<Image
        style={{
          height: 300,
          width: 250,
          alignItems: "center",
          marginLeft: 50,
          marginTop: 100,
        }}
        source={require("../images/Welcome.png")}
      />
      <Text style={styles.logintext}>
        Log In with your Data that you entered during your Registration.
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.btn1} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("signup")}>
          Sign Up
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.btn2} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("signin")}>
          Sign In
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make your initial state of 'loading' to true

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

Then add a timeout in the componentDidMount method like this

```
useEffect(() => {
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
  setLoading(false);
}, 2000);
return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank You for you support , its working fine but i want to display before my welcome page load, the loader is display after welcome page load. if you have any solution for that please let me know.

Comment: @TusharBhakare then you should add a new Splash-Screen and navigate to it first. After that, add the above timer to navigate to your home screen after a given time

Answer (score 0):

loadingText={'loading'}

worked for me to show the loading icon, when loading a Table

```
<Loader> Loading </Loader>
```

for other components in general.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).